# How much performance increase with streaming XPath

Tags: xpath, wso2, axiom, wso2-esb

Just read the article "[Streaming XPath Parser for WSO2 ESB](http://wso2.org/library/articles/2013/01/streaming-xpath-parser-wso2-esb)". I was wondering how much the performance increases with this implementation compared to the previous implementation.

Are there any numbers available on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://wso2.org/library/articles/2013/01/esb-performance-65) is the results of the latest performance test round done for the newly released WSO2 ESB 4.6.0 which uses the streaming XPath implementation and many more improvements. This compares ESB 4.6.0's performance with its previous release an also with some other ESBs. You will find this very interesting. Latest ESB pack is available [here](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/).

Comment: An interesting statement in this article is "WSO2 ESB 4.6.0 particularly focuses on XPath support for content-based routing". Here XPath will often be used to examine the value of a single element or attribute close to the start of the message, and this is a use case where the benefits of streaming can be dramatic. For other use cases they may be less impressive.

Answer (score 6):

I think you will have to make measurements for your specific use case (and you will have to decide what to compare against: different XPath implementations can differ in performance by a factor of 100). Using a technique like streaming will typically benefit some queries much more than others; and the benefits will also depend greatly on document size. It also depends whether you are looking for time savings or memory savings.

Caveat: I don't know anything about this specific implementation, but it was an interesting article.

Answer (score 5):

The objective of Stream XPath,where AXIOM will not consume the unwanted part of the steam, thereby reducing the memory and time taken to open an XML document as a Java object model.Basically we have observed it will increase the performance
   So If you carefully analyse the statistics e.g for CBR scenario in the Performance round 6.5 article [2], clearly it shows that it has doubled the performance compared to previous ESB versions.

[1]http://wso2.org/library/articles/2013/01/streaming-xpath-parser-wso2-esb
[2]http://wso2.org/library/articles/2013/01/esb-performance-65